# retrieve data from fragment

Tags: java, android

I want to retrieve String data from my fragment that sent from activity and I'm using this code to send :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name",texts.get(position));
CatSelected catSelected = new CatSelected();
catSelected.setArguments(bundle);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, catSelected, "CatSelected").commit();
```

And this code to receive :

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_frag, container, false);
    txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    txt.setText(getArguments().getString("name"));
    return view;
}
```

But `textview` is showing the default text and does not change. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common practice seen while using fragments is, not to directly instantiate the fragment. Instead, you a get a fragment object by doing something like below.

```
    MyFragment = MyFragment.newInstance(int arg1, String args2); // pass your args here
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
```

Now, the `MyFragment` is composed of

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int arg1, String arg2) {
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("arg1Key", arg1);
        args.putInt("arg1Key", arg2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        myArg1 = getArguments().getInt("arg1Key");
        myArg2 = getArguments().getInt("arg2Key");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second fragment or in your fragment that you want to retrive the passed value first must create a bundle.Try this.

```
  Bundle bundle = getArguments();
  txt.setText = bundle.getString("name");
```

Comment: hmm and what you want exactly pass data from one fragment to other or what?

Comment: i want to pass a string from mainactivity to my fragment. what you mean?

Comment: can you post a main activity and your fragment please , because it is a difficult to understand where can be the mistake.

Comment: or are you sure that you passed a value to fragment? did you log a texts.get(position) before send , because i dont see what can be the mistake in your code at the moment